# Cannot send HttpWebRequest with certificate from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, ssl, httpwebrequest, x509certificate

I'm trying to send a HttpRequest from my SharePoint 2007 WebPart to another web service. The service expects a X509 client certificate for authentication.

I wrote a simple console application that has no problem in sending the request and authenticating with my certificate:

```
byte[] certBytes = getBytes();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("<server_url>");
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes, "<password>", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But as soon as run the same code from my SharePoint Webpart it fails because it "Cannot create secure SSL/TSL connection".

Remark: If I don't use the X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet flag, I get "Access denied" on SharePoint. According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssecurity/thread/f1981374-5a25-45c7-aea8-aad859800ae7 the flag should fix this.

The (Apache based) web service logs the following error:

```
[error] Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?
```

Any idea why the same code works for my console app, but not on SharePoint?

Comment: Sharepoint server is running under a different account or user context. You have to add the client certificate into that user's context for HttpWebRequest in the webpart to be able to get it. Google for winhttpcertcfg and usage around it, and that should give pointers on how to make this work.